# Random playlists program

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

This is the first program I've created without help from a tutorial.  Written in Python 3.4, it gathers a specified number of media files and opens them in the default player (I use VLC on Windows 8.1). Python is my first language I have been learning mostly through trial and error. I am posting here to see what I can improve and to learn as much as I can.

```
import os, random, sys

completed_media = (r"C:\Users\user_000\Desktop\Completed Media")

all_media = []
playlist_ = []

def create_media_list():
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(completed_media):
        for file in files:
            if file.lower().endswith(('.mkv', '.mp4', '.divx', '.avi')):
                all_media.append(os.path.join(path, file))

def random_selection_from_media():
    random_selection = random.choice(all_media)
    if random_selection not in playlist_:
        playlist_.append(random_selection)
    else:
        pass

def get_selections():
    for i in range(number):
        random_selection_from_media()
    print_playlist_()
    playlist_confirmation()

def number_of_selections():
    while True:
        try:
            global number
            number = int(input('How many files would you like to add to playlist? >>> '))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Enter a number.')

def print_playlist_(): 
    print('\n-------In playlist-------\n')
    print('[{0}]'.format('\n-------------------------\n'.join(str(i) for i in enumerate(playlist_, 1))))
    print('\n-------End playlist------\n')

def remove_selection():
    while True:
        try:
            to_remove = int(input('To remove a selection enter the number of the selection you want removed here. >>> '))
            if to_remove <= len(playlist_):
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Enter a number.')
            remove_selection()
        try:
            playlist_.pop((to_remove - 1))
            break
        except (IndexError, UnboundLocalError):
            print('Enter a vaild number')
            remove_selection()
    clear()
    print_playlist_()
    playlist_confirmation()

def playlist_confirmation():
    ok = input('This list ok? >>> ').lower()
    if ok == 'yes' or ok == 'y':
        play_playlist_()
    elif ok == 'no' or ok == 'n':
        while True:
            new = input('Get new list or remove a specific selection? >>> ').lower()
            if new == 'new list' or new == 'n':
                del playlist_[:]
                clear()
                get_selections()
                break
            elif new == 'specific selection' or new == 's':
                remove_selection()
                break
            else:
                 print('Enter \'new\' or \'selection\'')
    else:
        playlist_confirmation()

def play_playlist_():
    for i in playlist_:
        play_cmd = "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler \"" + i + "\""
        os.system(play_cmd)

def clear():
    os.system('cls')

def main():
    create_media_list()
    number_of_selections()
    get_selections()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty good for a self-taught beginner, keep going like this and you're golden!

#### Recursion and infinite loop

This is probably the worst part of the script:

> ```
> def remove_selection():
>     while True:
>         try:
>             to_remove = int(input('To remove a selection enter the number of the selection you want removed here. >>> '))
>             if to_remove <= len(playlist_):
>                 break
>         except ValueError:
>             print('Enter a number.')
>             remove_selection()
>         try:
>             playlist_.pop((to_remove - 1))
>             break
>         except (IndexError, UnboundLocalError):
>             print('Enter a vaild number')
>             remove_selection()
> ```

An infinite loop, a misused exception handling,
an incorrect error handling, and recursive calls...
This is confusing and more complicated than it needs to be.

You can replace the recursive calls with `continue`.

Exception handling for converting the input to integer is appropriate, because there is no better way. It is not appropriate for validating the input is within range, because a better way exists using conditionals.

Also, it's not enough to check that the index is less than the length of the list, you also need to check that it's 0 or greater.

`UnboundLocalError` is thrown when trying to access a variable that hasn't been assigned. That's not an exception to catch, it indicates a problem in the logic that needs to be fixed.

Here's one way to address these issues:

```
while True:
    try:
        to_remove = int(input('To remove a selection enter the number of the selection you want removed here. >>> '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Enter a number.')
        continue
    if not (0 < to_remove <= len(playlist_)):
        print('Enter a valid number (within range: 1..{})'.format(len(playlist_)))
        continue
    playlist_.pop(to_remove - 1)
    break
```

#### Global variables

Try to avoid global variables as much as possible.

For example, instead of this:

> ```
> def number_of_selections():
>     while True:
>         try:
>             global number
>             number = int(input('How many files would you like to add to playlist? >>> '))
>             break
>         except ValueError:
>             print('Enter a number.')
> ```

It would be better to make the function return the `number`:

```
def number_of_selections():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input('How many files would you like to add to playlist? >>> '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Enter a number.')
```

And then adjust the callers appropriately to pass the number as parameter where needed, for example instead of:

> ```
> number_of_selections()
> get_selections()
> ```

Write:

```
get_selections(number_of_selections())
```

Adjust the rest of the code accordingly, and try to eliminate the other global variables too, `all_media` and `playlist_`.
For these two, another good alternative will be to create a class, where these variables will be member fields.

#### Simplifications

Instead of this:

> ```
> if ok == 'yes' or ok == 'y':
> ```

A bit simpler way to write:

```
if ok in ('yes', 'y'):
```

#### Optimizing imports, and coding style

The script is not actually using `sys`, so you can drop that import.

And the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends to import one package per line, like this:

```
import os
import random
```

Do read the style guide, it has many other recommendations that apply to your script.

Comment: I have edited my question with an attempt at creating a class to replace the global variables. It works but I'd very much appreciate you having a look at it, just to verify that its acceptable use of class. Also, thank you so much for your review I have learned a lot from it!